# batfile does not count correctly

Tags: batch-file

I've got a little .bat file with a script who counts the records in the database and saves it into a file. after that I compare the files. If the saved records are equal to the exported *.csv file.

in this case, my file has the right number. the csv file has as well the same number but not in in the variable.

second problem is that the number who is coming from my created file has a space on the end but I see nothing in the file.

```
chcp 1252
sqlcmd -S SQLSERVER\SQlINSTANZ -U User Id -P UserPass -d dbTable -s"" -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sync_Winkey" -h -1 -o "\\SERVERNAME\g$\Path\to\counter1.txt"


@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%b in (\\SERVERNAME\g$\Path\to\counter1.txt) do set temp_records=%%b 
  ::echo %temp_records%

for /l %%a in (1,1,100) do if "!temp_records:~0,-1!" == "s/" set temp_records=!temp_records:~0,-1! 

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=4 delims== " %%c in (\\SERVERNAME\g$\Path\top\file.csv) do set /A "winkeyFile+=1"
echo %winkeyFile% 

@ECHO ON

IF "%temp_records%" == "%winkeyFile% " GOTO CopyFile
goto:fail

:CopyFile
ECHO %date%
ECHO Daten wurden kopiert:
ECHO %time% Successfully copied. %winkeyFile% records copied
ECHO -----------------------------
PAUSE
goto:eof

:fail
PAUSE
goto:eof
```

Comment: Can you modify your question and show an example of `counter1.txt`?  Also, in your first `for` loop, what are you doing with token 5?  `%%b` will only capture token 1.

Comment: thanks for your hint with the 5. its not necessary. so I removed it. in counter1.txt its written the number from the SELECT COUNT(*) statement and it's written like that in the file
      33871

Comment: If `counter1.txt` contains a single line with a numeral, then perhaps a more graceful way to read it would be to `set /P "temp_records=" < \\SERVERNAME\g$\Path\to\counter1.txt`.  But I see another problem.  In your `if` statements, either remove the spaces around the `==` or use `equ` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Some problems with your code.

1) The space is not in the file. The space is in the code, at the end of the variable assignment

```
....) do set temp_records=%%b 
                             ^ here
```

Better change the line to

```
for /f %%b in ("\\SERVERNAME\g$\Path\to\counter1.txt") do set "temp_records=%%b"
```

Or, if the only data in the file is the number,

```
<"\\SERVERNAME\g$\Path\to\counter1.txt" set /p "temp_records="
```

2) There is no initialization of `winkeyFile`. It can be 0, or not

3) If the `.csv` file is readed with the indicated `for` loop, any line missing a 4th token inside it will not be counted. Better use

```
for /f %%b in ('
    find /c /v "" ^< "\\SERVERNAME\g$\Path\top\file.csv"
') do set "winkeyFile=%%b"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%b in (\\SERVERNAME\g$\Path\to\counter1.txt) do set temp_records=%%b
```

There is a trailing space on this line. Consequently, `temp_records` will be set to "somenumber<kbd>Space</kbd>"

Change this to

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%b in (\\SERVERNAME\g$\Path\to\counter1.txt) do set "temp_records=%%b"



  ::echo %temp_records%

for /l %%a in (1,1,100) do if "!temp_records:~0,-1!" == "s/" set temp_records=!temp_records:~0,-1!
```

I have no idea what you are attempting to accomplish with this line. It says: "If the contents of `temp_records` except for the last character is `s/` then remove the last character, and do this 100 times."

Note that again, there is a trailing space on the line, so ... and add a space.

This means (if the final ... and add a space is removed) that if the contents is `s/?`, replace it with `s/` - do 100 times.

Isn't the value supposed to be numeric? You don't provide examples...